# Tick labels for latitude and longitude on scatter geo maps in plotly

Tags: python, python-2.7, maps, plotly

**How do I add tick labels (ie. the latitude and longitude in degrees) to scatter geo maps in plotly (python)?**

If I take for example [Plotly's North American Precipitation Map](https://plot.ly/python/scatter-plots-on-maps/#north-american-precipitation-map) and within the `layout=dict()` add...

```
yaxis = dict(
    showticklabels=True
    ),
```

...nothing changes.

On the reference page, there is also a section for [Geo-Axes](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-geo-lonaxis), but none of the options under lonaxis or lataxis appear relevant for adding tick labels.

This is such a basic thing for maps that I'm sure I'm missing something, although I cannot find any examples on Plotly's webpage or elsewhere that have lat/long axis labels. How do I add these?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that adding tick labels to the `yaxis` doesn't work here is that this plot only has `lonaxis` and `lataxis`. Unfortunately, as you saw in the docs, these geo-axes don't support tick labels at this time. The `tick`-related options are for the graticule lines only.

Comment: Thanks @nicolaskruchten. Any idea if this functionality is in the works?

Comment: I don't see any open issues here https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js (which is where it would need to be implemented for it to work in Python) but you're welcome to create one! It's a tricky problem because many projections are supported so computing the location and angle of the labels is not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but in case this is useful to someone: you can add labels by using a "dummy" plot's text labels with mode=text. They have to be inside the plot area and thus will disappear when you zoom in, but it's better than nothing.

```
        # setup layout
        dtick = 30
        layout = go.Layout(
            showlegend=True,
            geo=dict(
                showland=True,
                lonaxis=dict(showgrid=True, dtick=dtick),
                lataxis=dict(showgrid=True, dtick=dtick),
            ),
        )

        # create figure
        fig = go.Figure(layout=layout)

        # add "label" trace
        x = list(range(-180, 180 + dtick, dtick))
        y = list(range(-90, 90 + dtick, dtick))
        xpos = -175
        ypos = -85
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scattergeo(
                {
                    "lon": x[1:-1] + [xpos] * (len(y) - 2),
                    "lat": [ypos] * (len(x) - 2) + y[1:-1],
                    "showlegend": False,
                    "text": x[1:-1] + y[1:-1],
                    "mode": "text",
                }
            )
        )

        # add any other traces 
        # ...

        fig.show()
```

if you prefer labels down the center vs. the plot edges, set xpos and ypos to zero, and the grid spacing is set with the dtick value. Should give you something like this:

[image]